# PiTunnel.com HTTPs tunnels for Ubuntu

Tags: http, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, debian, tunnel

There is a service for Raspberry Pi called Pitunnel.com. Among it's features, it's possible for me to access out of the LAN, a local Web Server on the Raspberry Pi using a HTTP Tunnel. Then amongt its features it is the HTTP tunnel that allows one to use a WebServer being hosted on the Raspberry Pi, on any port, not only 80, by using a pitunnel subdomain. Is there any service that helps doing the same with Ubuntu? Port forwarding on the LAN router is not an option, and it has to be accessed out of the LAN, over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several solutions, such as TeamViewer (it provides VNC but not for Ubuntu) and No-Ip (still requires port forwarding on the router) I found a simple free service called [LocalTunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) (I am not affiliated to it). The only problem is that it creates a new URL everytime it is started, but it solves my problem.